# Do Thundercats need to breathe?

Tags: thundercats

In several episodes of the 1985 Thundercats series, Thundercats show they don't need spacesuits when they are in space. However, in episode 91, Mumm-Ra threatens them with killing them, by drowning them in a trap with water, and Lion-O and Panthro say that if they don't get out of there, they are going to drown.

Do Thundercats need to breathe?

Comment: You could equally well ask "what was special about space around Third Earth that meant the Thundercats didn't need space suits?"

Comment: Dr Dometone episode: the shark suits seem to have air inside for breathing (and are watertight), so breathing underwater seems to be a no-go for Thundercats. There is also a lot of gasping.

Comment: +1 This is **clearly** the most important question on SFF.SE this week! Needs more attention! :)

Comment: @DanielRoseman It wasnt only in space around Third Earth, it was also close to Gray Prison Planet which is "a massive space station-like planet. It is hemispherical in shape. Located far away in space"

Comment: I don't think there is an in-universe explanation. Like SilverHawks, people breathed, spoke and even fell...down in space.